# JSON SCHEMA Adding dependant element with optional property

Tags: jsonschema

I have a JSON SCHEMA problem related to dependant elements.

Here is an basic example of elements who depends on "droplist", if you choose "Option1", both "example1" and "example2" are activated. If you choose "Option2", only "example2" is activated.

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "droplist": {
      "title": "Choose one",
      "type": "string",
      "enum": [
        "Option1",
        "Option2"
      ]
    },
    "example1": {
      "title": "Example field 1",
      "type": "string",
      "options": {
        "dependencies": {
          "droplist": "Option1"
        }
      }
    },
    "example2": {
      "title": "Example field 2",
      "type": "string",
      "options": {
        "dependencies": {
          "droplist": ["Option1", "Option2"]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Well, I want to achieve the following:

- Keep the dependant fields, but if I choose "Option1" and both elements "example1" and "example2" appear, I want "example2" with additional {"minLength": 3} property.
- If I Choose "Option2", I expect the original element "example2" WITHOUT minLength property.

Is this possible? Adding an extra property to a dependant element.

Summing up, I want element "example2" to appear with or without a property (minLength in this case), like a dynamic one.

Thanks guys.

Comment: Not exactly clear to me what you want to achieve but in general, conditional validation can be done using if/then/else (added with draft 07) keywords. Maybe clarify the question a bit and/or take a look at if/then/else.

Comment: I want to show an element of the Json Form, in this case, "example2", which DON'T have "minLength" property. It's like "Bring me example2, if Option1 is selected I want it with "minLength" but if Option2 is selected, i want the original example2 element, WITHOUT MinLength additional property"

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by splitting off your definitions to a place where they can be reused -- this is under `definitions` in versions up to draft7, and `$defs` thereafter. You are using the `dependencies` keyword, which was split into `dependentSchemas` and `dependentRequired` in draft2019-09, so I assume you are using draft7 (or earlier).

```
definitions:
  option1:
    ...
  option2_without_minLength:
    ...
  option2:
    allOf:
    - $ref: '#/definitions/option2_without_minLength'
    - minLength: 3
properties:
  ...
    ... things using $ref: '#/definitions/option1' etc
```